# What's wrong with Windows Task Sheduler + pytesseract + multiprocessing?

Tags: windows, multiprocessing, python-tesseract

Have the python code with pytesseract & multiprocessing. When I start the code manually from PyCharm it works fine with any number of threads. When I start the code with Win Task Sheduler with 'threads=1' it works fine.
However if I start the code with Win Task Sheduler with 'threads=2' or more than 2, it finishes without processing the images and without any errors.

I've got log messages like this. Script starts but does nothing and there is no any errors in Win logs

```
2020-05-24 13:09:31,834;START
2020-05-24 13:09:31,834;threads: 2
2020-05-24 13:10:31,832;START
2020-05-24 13:10:31,832;threads: 2
2020-05-24 13:11:31,851;START
2020-05-24 13:11:31,851;threads: 2
```

Code

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import datetime
from glob import glob
import os
import multiprocessing as multiprocessing
import cv2
import logging

def loggerinit(name, filename, overwrite):

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


    # create the logging file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename, encoding = 'UTF-8')

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s;%(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add handler to logger object
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger

def getfiles(dirname, mask):
    return glob(os.path.join(dirname, mask))

def tess_file(fname):

    img = cv2.imread(fname)

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_for_T = Image.fromarray(img)

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C://Tesseract-OCR//tesseract.exe'
    TESSDATA_PREFIX = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata'
    try:
        os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'
        tess_data = pytesseract.image_to_osd(im_for_T, output_type=Output.DICT)
        return fname, tess_data
    except:
        return fname, None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = loggerinit('tess', 'tess.log', False)

    files = getfiles('Croped', '*.jpg')

    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.info('START')

    threads = 2
    logger.info('threads: ' + str(threads))
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(threads)

    results = p.map(tess_file,files)
    e = []
    for r in results:
        if type(r) == type(None):
            e.append('OCR error: ' + r)
        else:
            print(r[0],". rotate: ",r[1]['rotate'])

    p.close()
    p.join()

    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()

    delta = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()

    print('Total time: ', delta)
    print('Files: ', len(files))

    logger.info('Files: ' + str(len(files)))
    logger.info('Stop.' + 'Total time: ' + str(delta))

    # Print error if exist
    for ee in e:
        print(ee)
```

Whats wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `try:`/`except:` is a way to silently ignore errors.

Comment: The code has try except, but it doesnt work. The job finishes every time& Thats it.

Comment: If you want to learn where the code breaks remove the code that hides the location.

Comment: You are passing relative path `Croped` to function `getfiles`. It could be working fine from PyCharm as you could be in correct path. But when the script starts from Win Task Scheduler, it may not be starting in the right path.

Comment: Nope, because if I set threads =1 then the code works fine either starting in PyCharm or by Task Sheduler. The problem occurs only if I set threads >=2  and start the file by Task Sheduler.